# calculate number of likes for every post

Tags: neo4j

I have following query to get one post with calculating number of likes:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)
WHERE post.uuid = {postUUID}
RETURN post,
       user.username AS `createdBy`,
       size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS `likes`
```

What I need is to calculate number of likes for every post individually.

My current query looks like:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(posts:Post)
RETURN posts, user.username AS `createdBy`
ORDER BY posts.createdAt DESC
SKIP {skip}
LIMIT {limit}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to clarify your question, it's a bit misleading. "for every post for list of posts" suggests that you're passing in a list for the posts, such as a list of post uuids, and cybersam's answer is making that assumption. If you are instead referring to paging (using SKIP and LIMIT) and want to calculate the number of likes for the subset of nodes you're returning, and you're not passing in any sort of list of ids, then please remove the reference to a "list of posts.

Comment: Thx, I changed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to reorder your query so you get the relevant subset of posts first, and then perform the additional matching and counting operations on that subset. That saves you from performing operations on nodes that won't even be returned in the first place.

```
MATCH (post:Post)
WITH post
ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC
SKIP {skip}
LIMIT {limit}
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post)
RETURN post, user.username AS `createdBy`, size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS `likes`
```

Comment: Works great! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the results for a specific list of posts (passing the list in a `postUUIDs` parameter):

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)
WHERE post.uuid IN {postUUIDs}
RETURN
  post,
  user.username AS `createdBy`,
  size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS `likes`
```

Comment: I don't specify postUUID here. It's simple request to get list of posts.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You mentioned you wanted "number of likes for every post for list of posts", which implies you wanted to specify a list of posts.

Comment: [{uuid: 1, likes: 2}, {uuid: 2, likes: 3}, {uuid: 3, likes: 0}]

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple aggregation:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)<-[L:LIKES]-(:User)
WHERE post.uuid = {postUUID}
RETURN user.username AS `createdBy`,
       post,
       count(L) as countOfLikes
```

Comment: Doesn't work when I don't have any like for specific post. Shows me only posts with at least one like.